# How to read Json data from Instagram RealTime API updates

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to use Instagram RealTime API to get updates whenever someone posts an image with an specific tag, I've followed all the steps, but I'm having problems to read the json data that is sent to my callback url. According to instagram's documentation :

> When someone posts a new photo and it triggers an update of one of
>   your subscriptions, we make a POST request to the callback URL that
>   you defined in the subscription. The post body contains a raw text
>   JSON body with update objects.

I'm using C# and MVC 5, here's my code to read the "raw text JSON body", note that I'm saving the json string in a text file.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpStatusCodeResult Receive()
{
    string json;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
    {
        json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), "test.txt"), json);

    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
}
```

The problem is, when I receive the request, the file is create, but is always empty. There's something wrong with my code? Could it be some problem with Instagram's API? I'd appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Just set InputStream position to zero and it works!